# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, .net-assembly

I have created an empty project in MVC 4 with .Net Framework 4.5 and integrated with sitecore
When I tried to run the project getting below error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040**

Comment: Does sitecore run 4.5 assemblies?

Comment: 1.try updating your web api assembly using nuget package update-package webapi. 2. check web.config for the assembly versioning for system.web.http

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add in some assembly binding redirects, although that's not usually one to redirect. As you haven't stated which Sitecore version you're running you may be trying to use older/newer assemblies compared to the Sitecore install. It's probable that you're using older binaries, Sitecore 8, 7.5 & 7.2 use MVC 5.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved :

You need the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package.

To install Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Core Libraries, run the following command in the  Package Manager Console

PM>  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
and you could add the below line before your class declaration

using System.Web.Http;

Hope its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your system assemblies from the sitecore install get replaced by a different version from your build. Make sure you set your system assemblies to "do not copy" in your project if they already exist in the sitecore bin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your reply!
Actually, I am using Sitecore 8 in VS 2012 which is not having MVC5.
So after installing MVC5 package in VS2012, it works fine !